# Air Android as3 sort array of files

Tags: android, file, sorting, actionscript-3, air

In my app i've included a folder of images, whose contents i'm adding to an array. Running on my PC it works fine, but on android the files are not sorted.

```
var rootpath: File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("./");
var imagefolder: File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("images/");
var list: Array = imagefolder.getDirectoryListing();

for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    trace("rootpath=", rootpath.getRelativePath(list[i]), list[i].nativePath.indexOf(".jpeg"));
}
```

The output on PC

```
//Output
rootpath= images/Slide001.jpeg 51
rootpath= images/Slide002.jpeg 51
rootpath= images/Slide003.jpeg 51
rootpath= images/Slide004.jpeg 51
rootpath= images/Slide005.jpeg 51
rootpath= images/Slide006.jpeg 51
rootpath= images/Slide007.jpeg 51
```

But the output on android

```
//Output
rootpath= images/Slide006.jpeg -1
rootpath= images/Slide002.jpeg -1
rootpath= images/Slide005.jpeg -1
rootpath= images/Slide003.jpeg -1
rootpath= images/Slide007.jpeg -1
rootpath= images/Slide004.jpeg -1
rootpath= images/Slide001.jpeg -1
```

So how can i sort the array by files name or `nativePath`?

Comment: where do you define `n`?  The iterator in your code is `i`.    While I haven't made an Android AS3 app in years and can't tell you the cause of the discrepancy (likely has to do with differing file systems); it's not hard to just sort the array in AS3 after you retrieve the directory listing

Comment: sorry it's i not n i will edit the question

Comment: I think **list.sortOn("name");** before the loop will suffice.